# Django FormWizard.as_view condition_dict callable called multiple times?

Tags: django, formwizard

The following is a snippet of how I have setup my FormWizard. When I hit this view function, 'bar' gets printed once and 'foo' gets printed 7 times:

```
# views.py
def _show_repair_item_form_condition(wizard):
    print 'foo'
    return True

@login_required
def workshop(request):
    print 'bar'
    cw = WorkshopWizard.as_view([WorkshopRepairItemFormSet, EmptyForm], condition_dict={'0': _show_repair_item_form_condition})
    return cw(request)
```

I have looked at the implmentation of the as_view function and can't find any trace of a bug causing this to happen. There is no documentation on the web about this issue either.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer, but this is not a bug, and nothing to worry about. Looking up the call stack for the condition function, you'll find the calls in wizards/views.py: `callable(condition)` and of course `condition = condition(self)` both call the function. For the former, `wizard.storage.current_step` will be `None`. Here is the source code for Django 1.6:

```
def get_form_list(self):
    """
    This method returns a form_list based on the initial form list but
    checks if there is a condition method/value in the condition_list.
    If an entry exists in the condition list, it will call/read the value
    and respect the result. (True means add the form, False means ignore
    the form)

    The form_list is always generated on the fly because condition methods
    could use data from other (maybe previous forms).
    """
    form_list = SortedDict()
    for form_key, form_class in six.iteritems(self.form_list):
        # try to fetch the value from condition list, by default, the form
        # gets passed to the new list.
        condition = self.condition_dict.get(form_key, True)
        if callable(condition):
            # call the value if needed, passes the current instance.
            condition = condition(self)
        if condition:
            form_list[form_key] = form_class
    return form_list
```

Comment: I still grable to understand this behaviour till today, it happens regardless of the conditions. I can understand it being called once per iteration, but I can't seem to understand why it gets called multiple times in the same iteration.

Comment: CONTEXT: the same behaviour persists as OP mentioned even in `django-formtools` which is basically the `FormWizard` packaged independently.